# configure toolbar to paste plain text django-ckeditor

Tags: django, django-admin, django-ckeditor

Can anyone tell me how to paste plain text in ckeditor using django's admin?
Everytime that I try to paste something from my clipboard it pops that message.

> Press Ctrl+V to paste. Your browser doesn‘t support pasting with the toolbar button or context menu option.